# Solving definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_{1}^{3}{\frac{1}{e^{-2x+4}+1}}dx$$

I'm asked to solve this definite integral, any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Please share some thoughts. What is the difficulty for you with this one?

Comment: I think I got it, I'll try multiplying by $\frac{e^{2x}}{e^{2x}}$

Comment: Please only one question at a time. I suggest you ask the new one in a new question.

Comment: Sure, i'll edit it out

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Find the derivative of $\log(e^4 + e^{2x}$).  Can you handle it from there?

Comment: yeh times by 1/2 right ?

Comment: I was giving you a hint, not the whole answer.  BTW, why is your username Insipid?  Do you know what that means?

Comment: it means bland, and i have another definite integral which i'll post on this now

Comment: the second one i struggled with for a while

Comment: Great hint. But try to utilise mathjax abit more. :) +1 in any case.

Answer (score 0):

By the change of variables theorem, chain rule, and fundamental theorem of calculus we have
$$
\int_{x}\frac{1}{e^{-2x+4} + 1} = \int_{x = \frac{-\log u + 4}{2}}\frac{1}{u+1}\cdot (\frac{-1}{2u}) = \frac{-1}{2}\int_{u}\frac{1}{u+1}\frac{1}{u} = \frac{-1}{2}\int_{u}D\log (u+1) + \frac{1}{2}\int_{u}D\log u = \frac{-1}{2}\log \big| \frac{u+1}{u} \big| + \text{some constant} = \frac{-1}{2}\log \big| \frac{e^{4-2x} + 1}{e^{4-2x}} \big| + \text{some constant}.
$$